# ASP.NET Webforms cause error on submit if listbox item is added by javascript and is selected

Tags: asp.net, webforms, viewstate

I have a listbox which is part of a composite control.

I add items by javascript. If I submit without selecting items(click on one or more of them), it works fine, but if I click on one of the items, it causes the following error.

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

I tried to register some possible values using Page.ClientScript.RegisterForEventValidation and it works fine for that values(in case when I selected one of them). So if I register all possible values, then i won't have problems. But the possible values are about 29000 int values.In my opinion, calling a service to get and register values is not a good solution.

Is there any other approach to solve this?

Comment: Do you know all the possible values that can be added to the listbox? This will determine which route you must take.

Comment: No, the values selected from and autocomplete list which always has newly added values.